# Что означает слово "кужалёк"?

Tags: значение-слов

Из песни: "...лён, мой лен, лен зеленой... ты удайся, ленок, ты удайся, мой белый  кужалёк..."

Answer (score 1):

В канонических вариантах песни, записанных в конце девятнадцатого века, никакого "кужалька" нету.

**[УЖ Я СЕЯЛА, СЕЯЛА ЛЕНОК…](http://a-pesni.org/rus/uzjasejala.htm)**

Однако в Инете есть фрагменты с "кужальком" в небольшом рассказе **[ТРАДИЦИИ ОБРАБОТКИ ЛЬНА У БЕРГУЛЬЦЕВ](http://xn--n1aemg.xn--p1ai/sibirskaya-glubinka/kraevedenie/176-traditsii-obrabotki-lna-u-bergultsev)**, - диалектизм, стало быть. Беларусь и вокруг. ("Гугл полный текст не наxодит... Это белорусская народная песня "Оx i сеяла Ульянiца лянок".)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Ох, і сеяла Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, і сеяла Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> Ох, сэрца — лянок,
>
> Мая радасць ты, лянок!
>
> **Ўсё бялюсенькі кужалёк!**
>
> Ох, палола Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, палола Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> Ох, і рвала Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, і рвала Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> А сарваўшы, у снапочкі ставіла,
>
> А сарваўшы, у снапочкі ставіла.
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> Ох, і слала Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, і слала Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> Ох, і прала Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, і прала Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> Ох, і ткала Ульяніца лянок,
>
> Ох, і ткала Іванаўна лянок!
>
> Прыпеў.
>
> А саткаўшы, ды сарочак нашыла,
>
> А саткаўшы, ды бялёных нашыла!
>
> Прыпеў.

---

Ещё [песня есть](https://vk.com/topic-167848269_38721286?offset=60):

> Сестрица, что прядёшь?
>
> Родненькая, что прядёшь?
>
> Сёстрица, кужалёк,
>
> Родная, кужалёк...

---

Белорусско-русский словарь

[**кужаль**](https://gufo.me/dict/beru/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)

***Очёсанный лён; тонкий холст, вытканный из льняных ниток, льняное полотно.***

Answer (score 0):

***Кужалёк - белорусское слово, уменьшительно-ласкательное от "кужаль"***.
Кужаль, собственно, и  означает очесанный лен и белый холст из такого льна.

Рассуждать про канонические и неканонические версии песен не буду, ибо это не для нашего ресурса.